# Problem with Fetch API using URL built by GetFeatureInfo in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, javascript, wms, getfeatureinfo

I request the feature info URL from Spanish land register WMS service successfully using:

```
const url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate,
    view.getResolution(),
    view.getProjection(),
    { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
);
```

Then I use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get the feature info URL in mode `no-cors`, but the result text is empty:

```
fetch(url, {
    mode: "no-cors"
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((html) => {
    console.log(html);
});
```

But having a look at Browser Developer Tools shows me that the Response of the URL gets successfully retrieved. For example [this URL](https://ovc.catastro.meh.es/Cartografia/WMS/ServidorWMS.aspx?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=catastro&LAYERS=catastro&TILED=true&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&I=19&J=110&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=225642.10749784112%2C5065634.7385152%2C225794.98155441147%2C5065787.61257177) shows this info in Network Response tab:

> Referencia catastral de la parcela:
>
> [8795224DF1789F](https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/CYCBienInmueble/OVCListaBienes.aspx?del=8&muni=244&rc1=8795224&rc2=DF1789F)

So why do I not have access to this response from Javascript?

Here is the complete example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-tile-forked-5tmits?file=/main.js).

Comment: If the source is not CORS enabled you can only load images, not data.  Either access the service via a CORS enabled proxy, or if the output is HTML which you simply wish to display without your code needing access to the contents use an iframe as in https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-tile-forked-9dzxrq

Comment: Are you trying to embed an HTML response inside an HTML page?  Does the text/xml response give you any different response?

Comment: text/xml does give me the same response. and yes, I'm trying embed the HTML response inside a HTML page. Thanks @Mike, I'll accept comment so please convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source is not CORS enabled you can only load images, not data. Either access the service via a CORS enabled proxy, or if the output is HTML which you simply wish to display without your code needing access to the contents use an iframe as in https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-tile-forked-9dzxrq